# Can ojdbc8.jar be used for connecting/querying Oracle XE using Java?

Tags: java, oracle

We are working on the RDBMS Adapter (i.e., to connect to Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, etc) creation. During connecting to Oracle DB we're facing JDBC driver issue for connecting different versions of Oracle Database.

**Isn't there any generic driver to connect to what ever the version of Oracle Database it may be?**

Like for connecting,

- MySQL  -> mysql-connector-java
- Oracle -> ?

Technology Stack:
Spring Boot
Java 8+ (Planning to go further also)
Angular JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are supposed to use the right driver for Oracle DB version and Java version. There is no generic driver that fits all combinations e.g. *ojdbc6.jar* driver does not implement methods introduced in JDBC 4.1+ (Java 7+).

See [What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDBC specifications?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_2) and [What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDK versions?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1) docs to understand which OJBDC driver you should use.